# Multiple routers with same SSID, WAN IP=0.0.0.0?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am adding some routers to my home network to improve weak signals in some areas. My primary router is WNDR 4000, and that one is connected directly to my cable modem. My first additional router is a WRT54G running dd-wrt. I have the ethernet cable in one of the regular jacks (not the internet jack). I set it up with the same SSID and password with the same encryption as the WNDR4000, disabled DHCP, and put it on a different IP address. Everything is working, or so it seems. I can connect to it using the new IP address, but when I view the router settings, it says the WAN address is 0.0.0.0. I don't think that is right, is it? When I hit the DHCP renew it still comes back with 0.0.0.0. I tried setting the WAN address to a static address once, and that made it so I couldn't connect to the router at all and I had to 30-30-30 reset it again to get it going again.

Is it normal for a router to have a WAN IP address of 0.0.0.0 when configured this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't hook the Ethernet cable into the Internet/WAN port on the WRT54G, you will get/see 0.0.0.0 in the WAN settings because it's not connected to anything. :)

You hard-set the LAN-side IP for the WRT54G router, and that's why you can access it using that internal IP.

From what you've described, and the fact that it works, tells me you're good to go as-is.

Aside: ensure you're WiFi channels are hard set to different channels in each router (especially if the signals overlap).  Helps with roaming.

Comment: Yes, I did hard set the wifi channels. I think I am good to go. I disabled the radios on my WNDR4000 and I still have internet through my WRT54G, so having no WAN is just fine.